# What software can be used to make this cartoon-like graphic?

Tags: vector-graphics, graphic-design, pixel-graphics

What software or fonts can be used to make the following graphic?

[image]

Edit: I think the font is from http://blambot.com.

Answer (score 2):

You could make such an image with a vector-graphics drawing program, such as [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/).

I can't identify the fonts, but I think that would be outside the scope of this site, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For these kind of projects I normally recommend [Adobe products](http://www.adobe.com/) (at least that's what I use for my projects) e.g Illustrator, as there are much more flexible and come with a lot of options.

However these commercial products need subscription or licensing so it depends on your budget, you can have a good comparison on which one is best suited (since they somewhat overlap functionality among them):

[image: adobe products]